# model.toJSON is not a function using Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

This :

```
@model
```

Returns :

```
Object { type="conjugation", verb="ser", yo="soy", more...}
```

But when I try :

```
@model.toJSON()
```

I get :

```
TypeError: this.model.toJSON is not a function
```

I am trying to eventually complete this line :

```
$(@el).html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))
```

So that I can render this object in a Show with my template.

Any recommendations?

**Update**

Persuant the comments. I have this as a model, but I can see now how they're are not related.

```
class AiProject.Models.Verb extends Backbone.Model
  paramRoot: 'verb'
```

I'm going to try and instantiate this type of verb.

```
class AiProject.Routers.QuestionsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @verb = new AiProject.Models.Verb
    @verb = options.words
```

And then back to my View :

```
class AiProject.Views.Questions.ConjugationView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/questions/conjugation"]

render: ->
  $(@el).html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))
```

Still get the same error though..

Comment: does your `@model` [`extend`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend) [`Backbone.Model`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model)?

Comment: Your model isn't a backbone model, but a plain javascript object.

Comment: @Yaroslav yeah, that's what it seems to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're setting your model correctly at first, then overwriting it with the value `options.words`.

Instead of this:

```
class AiProject.Routers.QuestionsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @verb = new AiProject.Models.Verb
    @verb = options.words
```

Try this:

```
class AiProject.Routers.QuestionsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @verb = new AiProject.Models.Verb(options.words)
```

That creates your model and passes in `options.words` to be set as the model's attributes.

Comment: Ah thanks so much Kevin! The syntax is becoming clearer and clearer to me. This worked perfffffectly. Thank you so much